# How can I change my variable value in an if else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, async-await

I am writing code for a discord bot in which when a staff member says a certain command the value of my variable will change but this is not working. Here is my code:

```
elif message.content.startswith("SMP ApplyForStaff"):
    if Staff_applications_status == True:
        await message.channel.send(Staff_application)
    else:
        await message.channel.send(Staff_applications_not_accepting)
elif message.content.startswith("SMP Applications-Closed"):
    Staff_applications_status == False
    await message.channel.send("Staff applictaions are now closed")
elif message.content.startswith("SMP Applications-Open"):
    Staff_applications_status == True
    await message.channel.send("Staff applications are now open!")
```

Comment: `==`  compares two values for equality.  `=` assigns a value to a variable.  They are not interchangeable...

Comment: But when I replace them I get this error: local variable 'Staff_applications_status' defined in enclosing scope on line 59 referenced before assignment

Comment: Then you need a suitable `global` or `nonlocal` declaration for the variable, so that you can access it within this function.  You haven't shown enough context for me to tell you which one to use.